# How do I dynamically update a <span> element depending on which radio button is currently active?

Tags: javascript, html, mustache

A mustache page in my web app displays all of a users desk bookings and allows them to select one using radio buttons. I'd like for a message displayed within span tags on the same page to be dynamically updated depending on which radio button they click using Javascript (or any other easier way).

This is what I've tried so far but at the moment, nothing happens when the radio button is selected:

```
<html>
   <body>
     <h3>Bookings:</h3>
     {{#bookings}}
       <p>Workspace: {{workspace}}</p>
       <p>Date: {{date}}</p>
       <p>Time: {{time}}</span></p>
       <div class="radio-wrapper">
         <input id="booking" name="booking" type="radio" onclick="updateMessage(this)" data-workspace="{{workspace}}" data-date="{{date}}" data-time="{{time}}">
       </div>
     {{/bookings}}
     <h3>Message:</h3>
     <div id="message">
       <p>
         Hi team,
         I just booked a workstation at the office. Let's collaborate! Details are below:
         <b>Date:</b> <span data-field="date"></span>
         <b>Time:</b> <span data-field="time"></span>
         <b>Workstation:</b> <span data-field="workspace"></span>
       </p>
     </div>
     <script>
       function updateMessage(radioButton) {
         if (radioButton.checked) {
           const workspace = radioButton.getAttribute('data-workspace');
           const date = radioButton.getAttribute('data-date');
           const time = radioButton.getAttribute('data-time');
           const message = document.getElementById('message');
           const dateElement = message.querySelector('b[data-field="date"]');
           const timeElement = message.querySelector('b[data-field="time"]');
           const workspaceElement = message.querySelector('b[data-field="workspace"]');
           dateElement.textContent = date;
           timeElement.textContent = time;
           workspaceElement.textContent = workspace;
         }
       }
     </script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your selectors are wrong

```
const dateElement = message.querySelector('[data-field="date"]');
const timeElement = message.querySelector('[data-field="time"]');
const workspaceElement = message.querySelector('[data-field="workspace"]');
```